# How to Query-By-Example with IN clause in spring-jpa?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a `spring-jpa` application and fetching rows from database with `query-by-example` like:

```
public List<Person> query() {
       Person p = new Person();
       person.name = "john";
       return dao.findAll(Example.of(p));
}
```

Problem: I want to add an `IN` clause, like:
`WHERE person.name IN ('john', 'jane');`

Essentially, an IN clause is the same as an OR matching on a specific field.

So I could achieve the same with `person.name = 'john' OR person.name = 'jane'`.

BUT: how can I add those conditions into an example object that obviously has no list property?

Comment: It does not look like the matcher is built for that.  Use CrudRepository `findAllByNameIn(List<String> names)`

Comment: Or `Specification`.

Answer (score 2):

As @Hitham S. AlQadheeb and @pirho hinted at, this is not supported by Query By Example. [The documentation explicitly states](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.running):

> Currently, only SingularAttribute properties can be used for property matching.

Use an alternative like Derived Queries, Specifications or a custom method implementation.